# Unknown element at the end of array in java script?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am relatively new to JavaScript so spare me.
While solving one of the problems at Freecodecamp which required to find unique values in two array's. I wrote a little piece of code.

It works well with arrays containing only integers. The problem arises when comparing string arrays. A trailing element gets added to final output array, an it is not even visible. It should only output one value for this piece of code.

Something like this.

```
"[*] Total unique values found = 2"
"[*] Unique values = pink wool,"
```

This is the code.Quite obfuscated it is.

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
  var newArr = [];
  var length1 = arr1.length;
  var length2 = arr2.length;
  var test = true;
  var tab = '     ';
  console.log('[*] Starting ... '+tab);

  while(arr1.length > 0 && arr2.length > 0 ) 
  {
    console.log('[*] Entering while loop.');
reset:
    for (var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) 
    {
      console.log('[*] Comparing '+arr1[0]+' and '+arr2[i]);
      if(arr1[0] == arr2[i]) 
      {
        console.log('[*] Matched ... ')
        console.log('   $ Removig '+arr1[0]+' from arr1 and arr2');
        arr1.splice(0, 1);
        arr2.splice(i, 1);
        console.log("   $ arr1 length = "+arr1.length);
        console.log("   $ arr2 length = "+arr2.length);
        break reset;
      } else if (i == arr2.length-1) 
      {
        console.log("   $ No match found.");
        console.log('[*] Pushing '+arr1[0]+' in newArr');
        newArr.push(arr1[0]);
        arr1.splice(0, 1);

        console.log('[*} newArr = '+newArr);
      } else {
        console.log('[*] Match failed.')
      }
    }
  }

  if(arr2.length > 0) {
    newArr.push(arr2);
  } else {
    newArr.push(arr1);
  }
 console.log('[*] Total unique values found = '+newArr.length);
 console.log('[*] Unique values = '+newArr);
}

diffArray(["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]);
```

Here is a link to [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/nedodo/edit?js,console,output) with working example.

Here is a link to [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hacipajuge/edit?js,console,output) with string array which not working..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When asking for help, please take the time to indent and format your code readably and consistently.

Comment: You don't need to use JSBin for examples, use [Stack Snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) to make your question executable.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip. I didn't knew about that.

Comment: The extra element is coming from `newArr.push(arr1)`. `arr1` is empty, so this puts the empty array as a new element in `arr2`, so it contains `["pink wool", []]`

Comment: Thanks for the help all of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is after your while loop iterating over the two arrays and comparing elements:

```
if(arr2.length > 0) {
    newArr.push(arr2);
} else {
    newArr.push(arr1);
}
```

You need to change the else to an elseif(arr1.length > 0) so that you're not pushing an empty array (what's left of arr1) onto newArr.

That being said, kevin ternet provides a much better alternative to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

just concat and filter doubles

```js
var diffArray = (arr1, arr2) => arr1.concat(arr2).filter((x,i,arr) => arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x));

var res = diffArray(["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "pink wool", "dead shrub"], ["diorite", "andesite", "grass", "dirt", "dead shrub"]);

console.log(res);
```

And in old javascript :

```
function diffArray(arr1, arr2) {
   return arr1.concat(arr2).filter(function(x,i,arr) { 
       return arr.indexOf(x) === arr.lastIndexOf(x)
   })
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that code never occurred could do that way.

Comment: Can you explain me the code a little bit, like what does this means =>

Comment: @Dimensionless Yes sorry. It's an arrow notation for function. I have traducted it at the end of my answer

Comment: I feels bad to see that it could be done in just 3 line of code, while wrote that long. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you write `newArr.push(arr2);` You're adding `arr2` as a new element to `newArr`.

[image]

I guess you wanted to concatenate arrays. To do this you can use `newArr.push.apply(newArr, arr2);`

[image]